# Need help with GTK# and mono

Tags: gtk, mono, monodevelop

In my quest for platform-independence, I built a simple hello-world app on my windows machine using monodevelop 4.0 and gtk# 2.12. When I try to run it on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I get the below runtime error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'MainWindow' from assembly 'hellogtk, Version=1.0.4824.3971,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED
>   EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'MainWindow'
>   from assembly 'hellogtk, Version=1.0.4824.3971, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.

My mono runtime version is 2.10. Can you suggest what could have gone wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answers to my question. On Ubuntu, below dependencies need to be furnished (apart from the mono runtime environment) before running a gtk# program compiled with Framework 4.0:

```
libgtk2.0-cil
libmono-posix4.0-cil
```